# Reading direction in pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I've a column contains Arabic sentences. when I try reading it by Pandas.read_csv , it reads it like English from left to right and I aim to the opposite.
e.g. row= [Egypt is big]
I NEED : [big is Egypt]
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65964265/edit), and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is split the string into a list, reverse the list and then join the list using spaces.

```
s='This is a string'
(' ').join(s.split(' ')[::-1])
```

What this does is it splits the string on spaces into a list, [::-1] reverses the order of the list, and then you bring them back together using the join method.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have you tried something like this to reverse the string characterwise?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['ab', 'cd']})
df['a'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1])
```